# Pasar un parámetro a un modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

Me encuentro con el desarrollo de un proyecto con `JavaScript`, `HTML` y `CSS`, y estoy con un problema a la hora de pasar un parámetro a un modal. Os comento más en detalle.

Tengo un archivo (controlWeb.js) `javascript` que se encarga de dibujar en el `html`, y sería donde se llamaría al archivo modal que se encuentra en el archivo `HTML` (index.html), este modal, necesita un parámetro (id) que le pasaría desde `controlWeb.js`. El modal, es el típico de ¿Estás seguro que quieres eliminarlo?, y si le damos a aceptar lo elimina y sino no, pues bien, si le damos aceptar necesitaría ese parámetro que se le pasaría de `controlWeb.js`. Estoy utilizando `bootstrap`. Adjunto código:

**ControlWeb.js**

```
//Más código que dibuja diferentes partes, incluido el boton que se ve


$('.eliminar').on('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).data('datos-id');
  //rest.eliminarEjercicio(id);//Esto es lo que quiero hacer en el modal
  $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: false});

});
```

**index.html**

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style='color:green'>¿Estás seguro que quieres eliminarlo?</h4>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Cerrar</button>

        // El id sería lo que quiero pasar
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="#" onclick="rest.eliminarEjercicio(id)">Eliminar</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es usar un elemento conocido, pues al estar todo en la misma página puedes acceder a su valor tanto desde el botón como desde la ventana modal. En este caso lo hago en un atributo personalizado en la propia modal (`data-id_elemento`), pero podrías usar un `input` normal o incluso una variable javascript global.

Se añade el *seteo* del id que quieres eliminar en el javascript, antes de mostrar la ventana modal, pues ya existe en el `DOM`: `$('#myModal').data('id_elemento',id);`

y en la ventana modal modifico la llamada del evento, llamandolo de la siguiente forma: `onclick="rest.eliminarEjercicio($('#myModal').data('id_elemento'))"`

El código completo quedaría así:

ControlWeb.js

```
$('.eliminar').on('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).data('datos-id');
  //rest.eliminarEjercicio(id);//Esto es lo que quiero hacer en el modal
  $('#myModal').data('id_elemento',id);

  $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: false});

});
```

index.html

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"  data-id_elemento="">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style='color:green'>¿Estás seguro que quieres eliminarlo?</h4>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="#" onclick="rest.eliminarEjercicio($('#myModal').data('id_elemento'))">Eliminar</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por contestar. Verás, me sale un error Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment en  $('#myModal').data('id_elemento') = id. Donde dices que usas un atributo personalizado `data-id_elemento` lo defines en algún lado antes o solo en el onclick del modal? Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Perdón, la asignación se haría así: `$('#myModal').data('id_elemento',id)` poniendo el valor como segundo parámetro. Fuente: https://api.jquery.com/data/  ya corregí la respuesta

Comment: Está definido en el HTML del modal, por alguna causa no se veía lo que había en el editor: : `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"  data-id_elemento="">`

Comment: Vale, lo he probado, sin embargo me sale como undefined el atributo id al pasarlo al modal. Por lo que he leído en esa documentación es así. Voy a ver si veo el error por el que es undefined. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, si tienes alguna sugerencia encantado.

Comment: El id de la línea `var id = $(this).data('datos-id');` lo captura bien, pero se pierde al pasarlo al modal.

Comment: Solucionado, faltaba mostrar que era el id a lo que haciamos referencia              
`onclick="rest.eliminarEjercicio($('#myModal').data('id_elemento'))"`

Comment: Ops!!  disculpa por la errata, me alegro que lo solucionaras :)